# Running apache flink job for some given amount of time

Tags: apache-flink, stream-processing

Is it possible to run apache flink job ( stream processing ) for some given amount of time like for one day between 11 AM to 11 PM. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a question: 
 --- Do you want to accumulate the data for 1 day and then process ? Like a batch processing

If not, just do a Tumbling Window:

```
   DataStream<T> input = ...;

input
    .keyBy(<key selector>)
    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.hours(12)))
    .<windowed transformation>(<window function>);
```